# Unexpected symbol near '<'

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I'm trying to code something in Lua where you must be exactly 12 years old to make it print `"Welcome!"`. However, whenever I run this code, I get an error message saying

> Unexpected symbol near '<'.

The error message says that this is on line 3. If possible, could anyone also point out the other potential errors in this code? My code looks as follows:

```
io.write ("Enter your age:")
    age = io.read()
if age == <12 then
    print ("O noes, you are too young!")
elseif age == >12 then
    print ("O noes, you are too old!")
else 
    print ("Welcome, son!")
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have Unnecessary `==`'s.

*Change the code to:*

```
io.write ("Enter your age:")
age = io.read()
if age < 12 then
    print ("O noes, you are too young!")
elseif age > 12 then
    print ("O noes, you are too old!")
else 
    print ("Welcome, son!")
end
```

When you are checking if a variable is **greater than** or **less than** another variable, you do not need `==`.

Example: `if (7 < 10) then`    `if (9 > 3) then`

---

*This may also be helpful:*

As this is your first Lua code, It may also be helpful to note that if you are checking if a variable is **greater than or equal to** (or less than or equal to) you would need to write it as `if (5 >= 5) then` or `if (3 <= 3) then`.

You only need `==` when you are ONLY checking if it is equal to the other variable.

Example: `if (7 == 7) then`

Comment: Thank you sir! You've fixed the old error message, but a new one is coming up now. The message is "Attempt to compare nil with number". It is on line 3. I have changed the script to what you told me to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. For the new error however, This error would come up because the variable age is a nil value, Perhaps because it is a string. Add  age = tonumber(age)  below age = io.read(). I believe this should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your further attempt at helping, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Which of the two suggestions of mine did you try?

Comment: I used the first one (tonumber), as I believe the second one was not what I was wanting my script to be (I want an input box, not a print)

Comment: Ok I see. I will write your code into my IDE and test It for errors and try to help you.

Comment: here is the current script, you're suggestions added in: http://pastebin.com/5LBwJ1ba

Comment: What IDE/Program are you using to write lua code in?

Comment: I am using lExecutor to run it and notepad ++ to write it.

Comment: I do not see any issues with the code. Perhaps it is a problem with lExecutor and the io library. You should try to do some research about IExecuter and see If others are having the same problem.

Comment: Just for confirmation, what exactly does it do? And also, I thank you greatly for taking time to help me :)

Comment: No problem, I am always glad to help. When I run your code it prompts me to enter my age. When I enter an age younger than 12 it says "O noes, you are too young!. When I enter an age older than 12 it says "O noes, you are too old!. When I enter 12 it says "Welcome, son!".

Comment: Yess, it works. I will do some research as to why it doesn't work for me. Once again thanks for your help